# Filtering Rows where Value has Decreased by x% then Flatlined in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Outline:**

I have a large dataframe of test results. Each test has a unique testID and within each test there are multiple unitIDs. unitIDs may appear in multiple tests. degCent values are listed at 1 second intervals for each unitID.

I want to filter for unitIDs where the degCent has declined by more than x% in a particular test and then flatlined.

This is best shown in a chart (the data extract is below). The chart shows the decrease starting at the beginning of the test but it may occur at any point in the data series:

[image]

So, in this example unitID 40190525 in testID 215299311 has declined from 30.2 at 19/06/2023 13:44:59.000 to 8.6 at 19/06/2023 13:45:05.000 and then flatlined from there.

**Detail**

First we need to calculate the decrease. For now I would like to identify unitIDs whose degCents have decreased by more than 70% from their high to their "lowest low" before flatlining.

From those unitIDs whose degCents have decreased by more than 70% I need to identify those that have flatlined. By "flatlined" I mean unitIDs whose degCents have stayed within +5% of the lowest low for 5 or more seconds.

I hope that make sense. It is a simple concept but not so simple to explain.

Please ask if anything does not make sense. I am relatively new to Pandas and am not even sure this is possible. The data is stored in a dataframe but if there is a better library I am ok with using that.

Thanks in advance.

**Example extract**

| testID | Date/Time | unitID | degCent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:44:59.000 | 40190525 | 30.2 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:44:59.000 | 28677460 | 4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:44:59.000 | 13180675 | 8.6 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:00.000 | 40190525 | 28.2 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:00.000 | 28677460 | 4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:00.000 | 13180675 | 8.6 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:01.000 | 40190525 | 22.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:01.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:01.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:02.000 | 40190525 | 15.3 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:02.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:02.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:03.000 | 40190525 | 12.3 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:03.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:03.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:04.000 | 40190525 | 8.8 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:04.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:04.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:05.000 | 40190525 | 8.6 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:05.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:05.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:06.000 | 40190525 | 8.7 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:06.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:06.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:07.000 | 40190525 | 8.7 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:07.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:07.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:08.000 | 40190525 | 8.8 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:08.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:08.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:09.000 | 40190525 | 8.6 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:09.000 | 28677460 | 3.95 |
| 215299311 | 19/06/2023 13:45:09.000 | 13180675 | 8.4 |

Comment: Can you have several peaks? Can the temperature increase? How should it be handled? Please provide examples

Comment: Hi @mozway yes there can be several peaks and the temperature can increase, decrease or not change at all. There willl generally be thousands of datapoints per unitID per test and so there could be lots of "noise". Another way of explaining it would be to say that if the lowest value at the start of the flatline is 70% lower than the highest preceding value then those unitIDs should be filtered.

Comment: OK, but those details are important, ideally provide an example of those and a schematic of a complex case with annotations of what you really need. Otherwise, I can bet the proposed answers will just be wasted time for everyone and you'll need to further explain the logic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1**

find **decreased by more than 70%**

```
output1 = df.groupby('unitID')['degCent'].agg(lambda x: (x.min() / x.max()) < 0.3)
```

output1

```
unitID
13180675    False
28677460    False
40190525     True
Name: degCent, dtype: bool
```

40190525 was decresed by more than 70%

**Step2**

find "**flatlined**"

Created series `s` where rows within 105% of the lowest were replaced with '1' and otherwise replaced with '0'

```
cond1 = df['degCent'] < df.groupby('unitID')['degCent'].transform(lambda x: x.min() * 1.05)
s = df['degCent'].mask(cond1, '1').mask(~cond1, '0')
```

s is too long, so let's just look at the top 5 lines

s.head()

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    1
Name: degCent, dtype: object
```

The results of these '0' and '1' are combined with strings for each id

```
s.groupby(df['unitID']).agg(''.join)
```

result:

```
unitID
13180675    11111111111
28677460    11111111111
40190525    00000111111
Name: degCent, dtype: object
```

and if there is '11111', it was within 105% for more than 5 seconds

```
output2 = s.groupby(df['unitID']).agg(''.join).str.contains('11111')
```

output2

```
unitID
13180675    True
28677460    True
40190525    True
Name: degCent, dtype: bool
```

all(include 40190525) have flatline.

and If you do boolean indexing by unitID, you can get only rows with that unitID.

Comment: Thanks Panda Kim. Will step 1 also find unitIDs where the minimum occurs before the maximum? I don't want this so just wanted to check.

Comment: Of course it is. If you don't want to, need to change condition.